# Using SQL (or T-SQL), How to get the length of Time a value was 0 or 1 each hour from a table that records the date and time a value was set?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a table with the following data:

```
        StartTime                     Value
 ----------------------------------------------    
    2016-12-20 08:09:00                 1
    2016-12-20 09:53:00                 0
    2016-12-20 11:10:21                 1
    2016-12-20 11:30:00                 1
    2016-12-20 12:20:30                 0
    ....                              ....
    ....                              ....
    2016-12-20 23:44:10                 1
    2016-12-21 00:33:00                 0
    2016-12-21 01:05:05                 0
```

So, what I'm trying to do is find how long a value was 0 or 1 during each hour, where the hours are from 00:00:00 - 01:00:00, then from 01:00:00 - 02:00:00 ... 23:00:00 - 00:00:00.
what I want to achieve looks like this:

```
    HourStart                 Period Value Was 0       Period Value Was 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-12-20 00:00:00                 50 min                   10 min
2016-12-20 01:00:00                  30                        30
2016-12-20 02:00:00                  32                        28
2016-12-20 03:00:00                  60                        00
2016-12-20 04:00:00                  21                        39
....                                ....                      ....
....                                ....                      ....
2016-12-20 21:00:00                  30                        30
2016-12-20 22:00:00                  20                        40
2016-12-20 23:00:00                  10                        50
2016-12-21 00:00:00                  01                        59
2016-12-21 01:00:00                  30                        30
....                              ....
```

By the way, I'm using Microsoft Transact-SQL.
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question and supply sample data which syncs-up with the desired results

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this:

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T as TABLE
(
    startTime datetime,
    value int
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('2016-12-20 08:09:00', 1),
('2016-12-20 09:53:00', 0),
('2016-12-20 11:10:21', 1),
('2016-12-20 11:30:00', 1),
('2016-12-20 12:20:30', 0),
('2016-12-20 23:44:10', 1),
('2016-12-21 00:33:00', 0),
('2016-12-21 01:05:05', 0)
```

Then, use a couple of common table expressions - one to get rid of the minutes and seconds of the start time, and the second one to get the start time of the previous row:

```
;WITH cte1 as
(
    SELECT  StartTime, 
            value, 
            DATEADD(SECOND, -DATEPART(SECOND, startTime), DATEADD(MINUTE, -DATEPART(MINUTE, startTime), startTime)) As startHour
    FROM @T 
), cte2 as
(
    SELECT  StartTime, 
            value, 
            StartHour, 
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ISNULL(LAG(startTime) OVER(Partition by startHour ORDER BY startTime), startHour), startTime) As minutes
    FROM cte1
)
```

Then, select from the second cte:

```
SELECT  startHour,
        value, 
        CASE WHEN value = 1 THEN
            minutes 
        ELSE
            60 - minutes 
        END as minutes_1,
        CASE WHEN value = 0 THEN 
            minutes 
        ELSE 
            60 - minutes 
        END as minutes_0
FROM cte2
```

Results:

```
startHour               value   minutes_1   minutes_0
20.12.2016 08:00:00     1       9           51
20.12.2016 09:00:00     0       7           53
20.12.2016 11:00:00     1       10          50
20.12.2016 11:00:00     1       20          40
20.12.2016 12:00:00     0       40          20
20.12.2016 23:00:00     1       44          16
21.12.2016 00:00:00     0       27          33
21.12.2016 01:00:00     0       55          5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm using Sql Server 2008R2 so it gave me an error (LAG is not a built in function). However, I found an article [link]http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/lead-and-lag-functions-in-sql-server-2012.html[/link] that explains how to achieve LAG functionality for versions prior to 2012. I should've noted that but I'll check your reply and mark it as answer if it works. And your request noted about the creation of the table with code. Thanks again

Comment: Actually my answer is wrong, as it doesn't take into consideration that the value might chabge multiple times in one hour. Will try to fix it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks. I will also try.

Comment: @ModernAristotle: In order to fix my answer I need to have sample data that correlates with the desired output. Currently, I'm not sure how to get the desired output since it doesn't match the sample data.